# I need to identify the following plants?

Tags: identification

I have bought these plants recently but i don't know their names

[Plants Images](https://plus.google.com/photos/105026230771918356682/albums/5775409609786251761?authkey=CNju7sPY67i79AE)

Can you tell me their names ?

Comment: Your questions won't help others a lot in the current format. You should make a question per plant (describing each plant in words (at least the size) and you should embed photos in your question instead of linking them from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick B. for advice
I'll take that into account next time

Comment: @AliEssam please edit this question to add the information that Patrick requested. All posts are editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick B's right in what he says - but I had a look and they're such easily recognizable ones, here's the list 1. *Codiaeum*; 3. *Syngonium podophyllum*; 4. *Coleus*; 5. *Dieffenbachia amoena*. Number 2 is the dodgy one, can't see it clearly, but could be *Philodrendron scandens*, or *Scindapsis* if it's variegated.

Comment: 2. is Philodrendron scandens